# Progress bar Java servlet and jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, progress-bar, progress

I'll try to explain my problem as clear as possible.

I developed an app (Java EE, servlet, jsp) where i try to read an excel file and make some request on different api to get some results for each line. That's mean the time to read the excel file and make all the request depends oh many line are present in the excel file.

I would like to inform to the user where is he on the process and for that, i'll need to implement a progress bar which one is according to the excel file.

Step on the app :

1. The user arrives on the home page, he uploads the excel file on the jsp page.
2. He click on validated button when it's ok for him.
3. the validated button redirect on the uploading servlet
4. On the uploading servlet, we read all the excel file and make the call to the differents api, when it's done, we redirect to the result pages jsp (upload jsp).

Do you have an idea to show the progress bar in percent in the 4th step ?

Thank's to all

Answer (score 0):

In this case make use of ajax call. Every time you progress with data read/api call reply to javascript function and progress the bar accordingly.

Comment: The problem is how to communicate between the post upload servlet and the home jsp to display in real time the progress ?